# Is using i18n module just for translating route names too much?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have the habit of coding in English and make everything in English so any developer can understand easily the code, but the problem i am facing using Nuxt is that all the page components that i create in English consequently have English names, but the userbase is from a different language. I have too options: using Nuxt i18n module just for solving this particular problem or changing all my folders and components names to the default language. Which one could be considered a better practice?

Comment: Your question was related to i18n, so I thought that you've considered nuxt-i18n out of the box.

Comment: The question was if using i18n module just for this purpose wasn't overkill, but thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code in english because it's universal and understood by everybody.
If the thing is language specific (something hard to translate properly or the exact name needs to be there in the original language to make sense), then *maybe* you could keep it that way.

Still, it would be having english rather than the translated language overall still. Having `MeGustaLaSandia.vue` is a no-go for example. Having `ILoveWatermelon.vue` is far better.

So don't think about it in the sense of too much, but more about: is it fine to have my project with this setup.

Also, you can totally have text as the translated language while still having your codebase in English, it's not like those SFC files are exposed anyhow.

Comment: The problem is that I really need the URLs to be in the userbase language. So in your opinion I shouldn choose the i18n way?

Comment: @Kos-Mos I never told that. The *code* needs to stay in english, what the end user sees can totally be in another language.

Comment: But this isn't an option with Nuxt because it has an automatic filesystem based routing.

Comment: A file in `/pages` and what you see in the URL is totally different. @Kos-Mos

Comment: No, it is not. If i name the file "something.vue" inside pages folder Nuxt will register the route as "/something"

Comment: Hence why nuxt-i18n is being used for that purpose: https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/custom-paths/